# How to get size of EhCache in version 3.1

Tags: java, ehcache

I know there is getSize() function in EhCache 2, but there is no getSize() anymore in Cache in version 3. Thus how to getSize()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cuero, by the looks of it, the 3.0 documentation examples still include getSize().
Check out the code example here: http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.0/getting-started.html#update-resourcepools

```
cache.getRuntimeConfiguration().getResourcePools()
.getPoolForResource(ResourceType.Core.HEAP).getSize()
```

Does that solve your issue?

Comment: The unit you used to define it.

```public String toString() {
        return "Pool {" + this.getSize() + " " + this.getUnit() + " " + this.getType() + (this.isPersistent() ? "(persistent)}" : "}");
    }
```

Comment: however this seems to be the defined size, not the 'used' size

Answer (score 0):

You can access the size of a cache in both the number of entries and bytes using the statistic service.

I explain in this answer how to configure it and gather the statistics : I answer this question here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49304590/3603660