# How to check how much memory is eaten Ehcache?

Tags: java, spring, caching, log4j, ehcache

I use **org.ehcache**, and collided with the problem that I can not know how many ehcache ate memory that would deduce to the console, I will be grateful for your help. using spring 4.1.6, **org.ehcache 3.0.3**.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ehcache cache size at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230003/ehcache-cache-size-at-runtime)

Comment: @shubham  No, your link on net.sf.ehcache, and my library org.ehcache, there is no class Statistics.