# Get size of entries in ehcache 3

Tags: java, size, ehcache, ehcache-3

I want to use ehcache3. For some junit tests, I need to know the size of entries in the cache. I dont find a method.
How can get the size of entries (not memory) in ehcache 3?

Greets

Benjamin

Answer (score 1):

For Ehcache 3.x you have the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49304590/12772281) from loicmathieu:

```
StatisticsService statisticsService = new DefaultStatisticsService();
CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
    .using(statisticsService)
    .build();
cacheManager.init();

CacheStatistics ehCacheStat = statisticsService.getCacheStatistics("myCache");
ehCacheStat.getTierStatistics().get("OnHeap").getMappings();//nb element in heap tier
ehCacheStat.getTierStatistics().get("OnHeap").getOccupiedByteSize()//size of the tier
```

You can check the official Ehcache test code [here](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/blob/master/integration-test/src/test/java/org/ehcache/integration/statistics/TierCalculationTest.java)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only for test, your best bet is

```
    int count = 0;
    for(Cache.Entry<Long, String> entry : cache) {
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: add  it.next() inside while loop

Comment: Right. Thanks. I made it even cuter.